# CSS Highlight text in a printable way

Tags: css

I have the following code that highlights text

```
<style>
  .yellow-bg {
    background-color:yellow;
  }
</style>

<span class="yellow-bg">This is some text</span>
```

This works in the browser, but when printed the text isn't highlighted unless the user digs into their print settings and checks "print background graphics". I can force it to print in Chrome with

```
body {
  -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact !important;
}
```

But that won't work in Internet Explorer.

Is there any way to use CSS to highlight text in a way that can be printed without the user changing their default settings?

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this using a border:

```css
.yellow-bg {
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.yellow-bg::after {
  content:'';
  border:100vw solid yellow; 
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:0;
  width:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<span class="yellow-bg">This is some text</span>
```

You can use this solution also to mark some text in a paragraph:

```css
.yellow-bg {
  display:inline-block;
  overflow:hidden;
  position:relative;
  vertical-align:top;
}
.yellow-bg::after {
  content:'';
  border:100vw solid yellow; 
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  height:0;
  width:0;
  z-index:-1;
}
```

```html
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, <span class="yellow-bg">sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt</span> ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur sadipscing elitr, sed diam nonumy eirmod tempor invidunt ut labore et dolore magna aliquyam erat, sed diam voluptua. At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum. Stet clita kasd gubergren, no sea takimata sanctus est Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</p>
```

... but this is limited to single rows only. In case you need to mark a multiline text this isn't working.